# How to prove $E[XY] = E[X^2]$ given $E[Y|X]=X$

Tags: proof-explanation, expected-value

Given $E[Y|X]=X$

I need to prove that $E[XY] = E[X^2]$

I'm not sure how to approach this. I would appreciate if someone could point to me what property of expectation I could use.

Comment: Is there no other information about $Y$?

Comment: This is wrong in general ! take $X$ and $Y$ independent and $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distrbuted.

Comment: As stated, this is wrong, so you can't prove it (I hope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, $E[X]=E[Y]$ is not enough to conclude $E[XY]=E[X^2]$.

However, the original condition $E[Y \mid X=x] = x$ is enough. Note that this last condition implies $E[Y \mid X] = X$. So,
$$E[XY] = E[E[XY \mid X]] = E[X E[Y \mid X]] = E[X \cdot X] = E[X^2].$$

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose First equality is [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). Second equality is due to $X$ being a constant that can be factored out of the conditional expectation given $X$; same reason as $E[2Y] = 2 E[Y]$. Third equality is already explained in my answer.